# Почему код возвращает именно такой результат?

Tags: c#, list, делегаты

Почему данный код возвращает строку вида 100, 100, 100..., а не вида 0, 1, 4, 9...

Прошу объяснить, кому нетрудно.

```
var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
      funcs.Add(() => i * i);
      Console.WriteLine(funcs[i]());
     }        
     var results = funcs.Select(f => f()).ToList();
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

Comment: У вас `results` - это результат выполнения функции, который приведен к списку - `List`. А `string.Join` объединяет все значения из списка `results` через запятую.

Comment: Почему выводится строка это понятно. Почему выводится именно 100? Я думал что будет выводиться 0, 1, 4, 9...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждая из ваших "функций" задана лямбдой:

> () => i * i

После выполнения цикла i = 10;
Поэтому в строке:

> funcs.Select(f => f())

10 раз выполняется умножение i*i, что и будет равно 10*10

Comment: А разве после выхода из цикла значение i остается доступным?

Comment: Как ни странно, да. Можете внутри цикла объявить переменную, которую будете использовать в лямбде (механизм замыкания). Тогда обнаружите, что будут созданы 10 независимых переменных и все их значения останутся для вас доступными(в лямбдах).

Comment: Хм, проверил. Действительно, если внутри цикла инициализировать переменную и передавать ей значение i, и использовать эту переменную в лямбде, то в результате получается строка вида 0, 1, 4, 9... Для меня это магия какая то)

Comment: @Tzarek, просто почитайте о механизме замыкания в .Net и все станет ясно

Comment: @Tzarek потому что замыкания https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/36601/

Comment: @Нетерпеливыйигуан - спасибо большое!

Comment: @John  спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В качестве дополнения к правильному ответу @Нетерпеливый игуан:

У вас переменная цикла — одна и та же в каждой итерации, поэтому замыкания захватывают одну и ту же, меняющуюся переменную. Если вы хотите захватить *значение*, скопируйте его в локальную переменную:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var local_i = i;
    funcs.Add(() => local_i * local_i);
    Console.WriteLine(funcs[local_i]());
}
```

Переменная `local_i` на каждой итерации *своя*, а значит, изменения `i` на неё не повлияют.